# Do closure and intersection of open sets commute when composed with the interior?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

In the [Wikipedia article on the interior operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Interior_operator) it is stated that on a complete metric space $X$ one has for every sequence of **open** sets $(A_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}\subset X$ the relation
$$
\mathrm{Int}\Big(\bigcap_{i}\overline A_i\Big)=\mathrm{Int}\Big(\overline {\bigcap_{i}A_i}\Big).
$$
Now I wonder whether the finite version of this relation, i.e., for any two **open** sets $A,B\subset X$ to have
$$
\mathrm{Int}\big(\overline A\cap \overline B\big)=\mathrm{Int}\big(\overline {A\cap B}\big),
$$
does actually hold in any topological space $X$. If so, it should be found in some elementary textbooks, perhaps as an exercise. I searched for a while but it turned out that searching for relations like this is extremely inconvenient - one obtains hundreds of results which are similar but different from the wanted relation. On the other hand, I guess that (if the relation holds in general) there should be an easy direct proof based on playing around with the operations interior, closure, intersection, union, and complement. Since I don't have enough time for  this game I'm asking directly for a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a standard fact used in the theory of so-called regular-open sets (sets such that $\operatorname{int}(\overline{U})=U$; your sets of the form "interior of closure" are regular open..) and forms part of the proof that those sets form a Boolean algebra under the operations $U \land V = U \cap V$, $U \lor V = \operatorname{int}(\overline{U \cup V})$ and $\lnot U = \operatorname{int}U^\complement$. I think Halmos proves it in his Boolean algebra book, and it's also in Engelking somewhere, I'm sure.

As $\overline{A \cap B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$, because $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ and likewise for $B$, so $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ is a closed superset of $A \cap B$, so it contains $\overline{A \cap B}$ too. Taking interior on both sides gives the easy inclusion (we don't need anything on $A$,$B$):

$$\operatorname{int}(\overline{A \cap B})\subseteq \operatorname{int}(\overline{A} \cap \overline{B})$$

For the reverse inclusion we can use a small lemma that for an open $U$ and any $A$ we have $\overline{U \cap A} = \overline{U \cap \overline{A}}$. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of the other direction.

It suffices to show that $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})\subseteq \overline{A\cap B}$, because $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})$ is open, so if it's a subset of some set, it's a subset of the interior of it.

Since $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A\cap\overline{B}}$, it suffices to show $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})\subseteq \overline{A\cap\overline{B}}$.

Let $x\in\operatorname{int}(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})$.  Let $W$ be an open neighborhood of $x$.  Then so is $V=W\cap\operatorname{int}(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})$.  Since $x\in\overline{A}$, there exists some $y\in V\cap A$.  Since $V\subseteq \overline{B}$ then $y\in V\cap A\cap\overline{B}\subseteq W\cap A\cap\overline{B}$.  This was for an arbitrary open neighborhood $W$ of $x$ - proving that $x\in \overline{A\cap\overline{B}}$.

To show $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A\cap\overline{B}}$, let $U$ be an open set.  If $U\cap A\cap B\ne\emptyset$ then certainly $U\cap A\cap\overline{B}\ne\emptyset$.  Conversely, if $U\cap A\cap\overline{B}\ne\emptyset$, let $t\in U\cap A\cap\overline{B}$.  Since $U\cap A$ is an open neighborhood of $t$ and $t\in\overline{B}$ then $U\cap A\cap B\ne\emptyset$.  We've shown that $U\cap A\cap B\ne\emptyset$ iff $U\cap A\cap\overline{B}\ne\emptyset$ for any open set $U$.  This proves that $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A\cap\overline{B}}$.