# Interior of intersection of essential closures

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request

Let $X$ be a topological space. Then any two **open** sets $A,B\subset X$ satisfy
$$
\mathrm{Int}\big(\overline A\cap \overline B\big)=\mathrm{Int}\big(\overline {A\cap B}\big),
$$
as explained in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044448/do-closure-and-intersection-of-open-sets-commute-when-composed-with-the-interior). It is easy to see that the above equality does not hold for arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$. For example, consider  $X=\mathbb R$, $A=\mathbb Q$, $B=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$. (However, it seems to be somewhat difficult to write down a counterexample in $\mathbb R$ where one of the sets is open).

Now, suppose that there is a measure $\mu$ on $X$ on some $\sigma$-algebra containing the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Recall that the essential support of a measurable function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is defined by
$$
\mathrm{ess\,supp}\, f=X\setminus\bigcup\big\{\Omega\subset X \;|\; \Omega \text{ open},\; f=0\text{ almost everywhere in }\Omega\big\}.
$$
Given some measurable set $A\subset X$, let us define its *essential closure* by
$$
\overline{A}^\mu:=\mathrm{ess\,supp}\, 1_A,
$$
where $1_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$.

I am interested in the question which measurable sets $A,B\subset X$ satisfy the equality
$$
{(\bf I)}\qquad\mathrm{Int}\big(\overline A^\mu\cap \overline B^\mu\big)=\mathrm{Int}\big(\overline {A\cap B}^\mu\big).
$$
If the measure $\mu$ is strictly positive, i.e., $\mu(U)>0$ for every non-empty open set $U\subset X$, then one has $\overline A^\mu=\overline A$ for every open set $A$ and thus ${\bf(I)}$ holds for any two open sets $A,B$.
On the other hand, if the support of the measure $\mu$ has empty interior (e.g. a Dirac measure on a space where points have empty interior), then ${\bf(I)}$ holds trivially for any two measurable sets $A,B$.

I expect that there should be plenty of counterexamples to ${\bf(I)}$ even when $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. However, I find it surprisingly difficult to find such counterexamples. For example, the above pair $A=\mathbb Q$, $B=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ no longer works. Also $A=C$, the fat Cantor set, and $B =\mathbb R\setminus C$ does not work.

**Who knows a counterexample to ${(\bf I)}$ ?**

Preferably with $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, but other topological measure spaces would also be interesting.

A reference where such questions are addressed would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have found a counterexample myself, inspired by the exercises on p. 118 of Bressoud's *A radical approach to Lebesgue's theory of integration*. Let me share it with you:

We take $X=[0,1]$, $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, and let $(\lambda_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}\subset (0,\infty)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that
$$
L:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k<\infty.
$$
Put $a_k:=e^{-\lambda_k}(1+2e^{-\lambda_k})$ and denote by $C_{a_k}\subset [0,1]$ the  Smith–Volterra–Cantor set with parameter $a_k$. The latter has the volume $1-e^{-\lambda_k}$. Let $C_1:=C_{a_1}$ and for $n\geq 2$ let $C_n$ be defined by replacing each open interval in $[0,1]\setminus\{C_1\cup\cdots\cup C_{n-1}\}$ with a rescaled version of $C_{a_n}$. Note that $C_n$ is disjoint from $C_k$ for all $k<n$. Then one has
$$
\mu(C_1\cup \cdots \cup C_n)=1-e^{-\sum_{k=1}^N\lambda_k},
$$
which implies that $C:=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty C_k$ satisfies
$$
\mu(C)=1-e^{-L}>0,\qquad \mu([0,1]\setminus C)=e^{-L}>0.
$$
Now, if $(a,b)\subset [0,1]$ is a non-empty open interval, then since each SVC-set is nowhere dense the above procedure places a small rescaled version of $C_{a_k}$ inside $(a,b)$ for some large enough $k$, so a similar argument as above shows that
$$\mu((a,b)\cap C)>0,\qquad \mu((a,b)\cap ([0,1]\setminus C))>0.$$
This shows that $\mu(\Omega\cap C)>0$ and $\mu(\Omega\cap (X\setminus C))>0$ for *every* non-empty open set $\Omega\subset [0,1]=X$, so that
$$
\overline{C}^\mu=X,\qquad \overline{X\setminus C}^\mu=X.
$$
However, $\overline{C\cap(X\setminus C)}^\mu=\overline{\emptyset}^\mu=\emptyset$, so $A:=C$ and $B:=X\setminus C$ provide a counterexample to **(I)**.